# change range-progress color with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello i have this input type range with min and max value.

and i want to change the range progress color for now all is black

```
<section class="range-slider car-mileage-range">

  <input value="10" min="10" max="41181" step="1" type="range">
  <input value="41181" min="10" max="41181" step="1" type="range">
</section>
```

this is my css :

```
section.range-slider input {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100% !important;
    outline: none;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section.range-slider input {
    width: 100% !important;
}
input[type="range"] {
    height: 2px !important;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
input[type="range"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    border-radius: 1px !important;
}
```

so to change the progress color i have tried to use :

```
input[type=range]::range-progress {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1em;
  color: red;
}
```

and also :

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1em;
}
```

but none of this is working for me 
is there a css or javascript method to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-element `::-moz-range-progress` works only in Firefox. For another browser supporting use following:

```
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But that works for `<progress>` element instead input with type 'range'. Also see: `webkit-progress-bar`, `moz-progress-bar`.
For inputs you should pay attention for following pseudo-elements:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb
```

those can help you customize your inputs

Comment: yes thank you but no one of them let me change the color if the range is in progress

Comment: perhaps, it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392447/how-to-style-input-type-range, or this one: https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#Bblue").css({"accent-color": "green"});
    
  });
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  accent-color: red;
}

#Bblue {
  accent-color: blue;
}

h3 {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
      <h3>Background different color range slide bootstrap</h3><br/>
        
<input type="range" id="MaasTercih" class="form-range customRange" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="range" id="Bblue" class="form-range customRange" />
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="btn">Change Color Blue to Green</button>
```

Comment: Could you add some details on what you change and why in order for other to learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you and I need; I spent a heck of a time searching about it. It really seemed to be unfindable.

HTML:

```
<main>
<input type="range" class="win10-thumb" />
<input type="range" class="win10-thumb" min="0" max="100" value="25" step="5" />
<input type="range" class="win10-thumb" disabled value="64" />
<input type="range" />
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="40" step="5" />
<input type="range" disabled value="80" /></main>
```

CSS:

```
  /*
 * 16 February 2022
 * Range Slider Progress in Chrome with pure CSS
 *
 * === This CodePen demonstrates how we can implement range slider "progress fill" in Webkit browsers using a `clip-path` and a `box-shadow` ===
 *
 * === There is an open issue about Standardizing input[type="range"] styling (https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4410). For all I know, it hasn't been implemented yet ===
 *
 * === This demo is meant for Chrome browsers. But it'll also work in Firefox because Firefox provides the `::-moz-range-progress` pseudo-class ===
 *
 * more info. in the details view
 *
 */

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2.2em;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

html::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #fff, #fafafa);
    display: block;
}

/* === range theme and appearance === */
input[type="range"] {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 12.5em;
}

input[type="range"] {
    color: #ef233c;
    --thumb-height: 1.125em;
    --track-height: 0.125em;
    --track-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    --brightness-hover: 180%;
    --brightness-down: 80%;
    --clip-edges: 0.125em;
}

input[type="range"].win10-thumb {
    color: #2b2d42;

    --thumb-height: 1.375em;
    --thumb-width: 0.5em;
    --clip-edges: 0.0125em;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    html {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    html::before {
        background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #101112, #000);
    }

    input[type="range"] {
        color: #f07167;
        --track-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    input[type="range"].win10-thumb {
        color: #3a86ff;
    }
}

/* === range commons === */
input[type="range"] {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="range"]:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

input[type="range"]:disabled {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    opacity: 0.3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

/* === WebKit specific styles === */
input[type="range"],
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    transition: all ease 100ms;
    height: var(--thumb-height);
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    --thumb-radius: calc((var(--thumb-height) * 0.5) - 1px);
    --clip-top: calc((var(--thumb-height) - var(--track-height)) * 0.5 - 0.5px);
    --clip-bottom: calc(var(--thumb-height) - var(--clip-top));
    --clip-further: calc(100% + 1px);
    --box-fill: calc(-100vmax - var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height))) 0 0
        100vmax currentColor;

    width: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));
    background: linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) scroll no-repeat left center /
        50% calc(var(--track-height) + 1px);
    background-color: currentColor;
    box-shadow: var(--box-fill);
    border-radius: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));

    filter: brightness(100%);
    clip-path: polygon(
        100% -1px,
        var(--clip-edges) -1px,
        0 var(--clip-top),
        -100vmax var(--clip-top),
        -100vmax var(--clip-bottom),
        0 var(--clip-bottom),
        var(--clip-edges) 100%,
        var(--clip-further) var(--clip-further)
    );
}

input[type="range"]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-hover));
    cursor: grab;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-down));
    cursor: grabbing;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--track-color) 0 0) scroll no-repeat center /
        100% calc(var(--track-height) + 1px);
}

input[type="range"]:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

/* === Firefox specific styles === */
input[type="range"],
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    transition: all ease 100ms;
    height: var(--thumb-height);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background: #fff0;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: currentColor;
    border: 0;
    width: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));
    border-radius: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));
    cursor: grab;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--track-color);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    appearance: none;
    background: currentColor;
    transition-delay: 30ms;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    height: calc(var(--track-height) + 1px);
    border-radius: var(--track-height);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    filter: brightness(100%);
}

input[type="range"]:hover::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]:hover::-moz-range-progress {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-hover));
}

input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-progress {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-down));
}

input[type="range"]:disabled::-moz-range-thumb {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```